# Laravel 4 Mail Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument

Tags: php, email, utf-8, laravel-4, arguments

I'm having an issue.

I try to send an activation link when the user signs up but the mail class keeps giving me this error:

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument","file":"C:\\BitNami\\wampstack-5.4.25-0\\apache2\\htdocs\\zplus\\vendor\\filp\\whoops\\src\\Whoops\\Handler\\JsonResponseHandler.php","line":106}}
```

I changed the variables `$message`, `$subject`, and even the email `$email`.Nothing works and I cannot solve the problem.

If I remove the mail function, then there are no problems.

**Controller code**

```
$email = Input::get('email');

Mail::queue('emails.auth.activate', array('activation_code' => $activation_code), function($message) use ($email)
{
    $message->to($email, "ZL")->subject(trans("global.user_activation"));
});

Auth::loginUsingId($this->user->id);

$data = array('status' => 'success', 'redirect' => URL::to('/'));

return Response::json($data);
```

Could please someone help me out?

Comment: The problem might be in `trans("global.user_activation")`. Maybe the translation doesn't contain valid utf8 sequence. Replace it with normal english string to see if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was caused by `'driver' => 'sendmail'` in `app/config/mail.php`. Try to use other driver or `smpt`.